# Rand post related question

Tags: posts

I've used that code in my function file to randomise posts in a category and keep the order in the pagination...

```
session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

The problem is that every time the user comes back to the website, he sees the same order. Is there a way to add a time component to the session? like 30 mins or so to reset itself?

Answer (score 1):

This is more a generic PHP question, but for what it's worth:

```
if ( empty( $_SESSION['seed_time'] ) )
    $_SESSION['seed_time'] = time();

if ( empty( $_SESSION['seed'] ) || time() > ( $_SESSION['seed_time'] + 30 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS ) ) {
    // Seed session is empty, or session time is older than 30 minutes, generate new seed
    $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed = rand();
    $_SESSION['seed_time'] = time();
} else {
    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
}   

return "RAND($seed)";
```